# Issue with Yii RBAC AuthManager and Bizrules

Tags: php, yii, rbac

Example: I want to allow someone to update only specific blog posts.

I would think the rules would be laid out like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$auth->createOperation('update_post_category', '', 'return ( $params["category"] == $data["category"] );');

$role = $auth->createRole('PostEditor');
$role->addChild('update_post_category');

$auth->assign('PostEditor', 'username', null, array('category' => 7));
```

Looking at the Yii code I understand why. But how would I go about implementing this? I could go about adding a bizrule for every assignment, but I think that's rather bloated; there must be a better way, right?

Comment: This has been addressed in a [recent post][1] here.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109990/how-to-implement-user-can-delete-his-own-posts-on-the-role-based-access-contr/13110311#13110311

Comment: @BoazRymland, that is a different issue and does not help me.